# disable buttons and menu bar when calling subprocess then enable them in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

i want to disable buttons when i call subprocess to execute another tkinter window and to prevent multi-showing windows when i click too many times on buttons, then after finishing from the second calling window i want to re-enable them.

> menubar.entryconfig("tester", state="disabled") and
> menubar.entryconfig("tester", state="normal")
> both of them in the same function does not ndo the trick. is there any other way to do it. And thanks in advance.

```
# add the necessairy librairy
import tkinter as tk
import subprocess

def Region_windows2():

    menubar.entryconfig("tester", state="disabled")
    menubar.entryconfig("tester2", state="disabled")
    menubar.entryconfig("tester3", state="disabled")
    subprocess.call(['/home/pi/test3/script.sh'])
    menubar.entryconfig("tester", state="normal")

# here's the main window
Mafenetre = tk.Tk()
#set main window title
Mafenetre.title("GUI")
Mafenetre['bg']='white' # couleur de fond
# get screen width and height
wf1= Mafenetre.winfo_screenwidth()
hf1= Mafenetre.winfo_screenheight()
A = str(wf1)
B = str(hf1)
# set the dimensions of the screen 
# and where it is placed
Mafenetre.geometry(A+"x"+B)
Mafenetre.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
# add menubar to the main window
menubar = tk.Menu(Mafenetre, bg='#1f1b13', fg='white')
# menubar button to test the second window
menubar.add_command(label="tester", command=Region_windows2)
menubar.add_command(label="tester2", command=hello)
menubar.add_command(label="tester3", command=hello)
# add menubr to the main window
Mafenetre.config(menu=menubar)

pwd = tk.Entry(Mafenetre, show="*")
pwd.pack()
pwd.focus()

Mafenetre.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try adding `menubar.update()` before calling `subprocess.call(...)`.

Comment: adding menubar.update() before execute subprocess.call(...) twice when clicking too many times on the button.  adding it after subprocess.call(...)  does the trick. thanks any way.